# Network-X edge_betweeness_centrality function does not take weight into account

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to randomize the link weights of a network x graph to change the betweenness centrality of that network. I have verified that the weights do change but it does not change the output of the edge_betweeness_centrality function. I suspect it has something to do with adding objects to the nodes and edges as I was able to get it working as long as I didn't have these. However, I need the objects for other parts of my code so deleting them isn't an option.

I have tried load_centrality and betweenness_centrality and both give me the same issue. I have also verified my inputs are integers or floats. I understand the functions interpret the values as distances so I have tried both the normal weight and the reciprocal of the weight. I've been stuck on this issue for weeks and would appreciate any help or ideas. Thank you.

The following is my code.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np 
from itertools import combinations, groupby
import random 

class Link(object):
  def __init__(self,link_id,rate,distance,network):
        self.link_id = link_id 
        self.rate = rate
        self.distance = distance
        self.network = network
        self.buffer = [] 

class Node:
    def __init__(self,node_id,network): 
        self.node_id = node_id
        self.len = 0   
        self.queue = []
        self.network = network
        self.packet_delay = []
        self.packets = []

def gnp_random_connected_graph(n, p):
        graph_seed = np.random.default_rng(2021)

        network = nx.Graph()
        
        node_dict = {}
        for node in range(n):
            new_node = Node(node, network)
            node_dict[node] = new_node
            

        network.add_nodes_from(node_dict.items())

        edges = list(combinations(range(n), 2))
        link_dict = {}
        for id, node_edges in groupby(edges, key=lambda x: x[0]): 
            rate = random.randint(8000000,40000000) #bps
            distance = random.randint(10,185) #meters
            node_edges = list(node_edges) 
            random_edge = tuple(graph_seed.choice(node_edges))
            link_dict[random_edge] = Link(random_edge,rate,distance,network)
        
        for e in node_edges:  
            if graph_seed.random() < p: 
                link_dict[e] = Link(e,rate,distance,network)

        for key,value in link_dict.items(): 
            nodes = list(network.nodes)
            network.add_edge(nodes[key[0]],nodes[key[1]],obj=value,weight=int(value.distance),rp = float(1/(value.distance)))
            
        return network        

def randomize_weights(network):

            for edge in network.edges():
                rand_num = random.randint(10,100) 
                network[edge[0]][edge[1]]['weight'] = rand_num
                network[edge[0]][edge[1]]['rp'] = 1/rand_num

            return network  


org_net = gnp_random_connected_graph(10,.1)
#print("edges weight",nx.get_edge_attributes(org_net,'weight'))
bc_dict = nx.edge_betweenness_centrality(org_net, weight='rp')
print("OLD",bc_dict)
new_net = randomize_weights(org_net.copy())
#print("edges weight",nx.get_edge_attributes(new_net,'weight'))
new_bc_dict = nx.edge_betweenness_centrality(new_net, weight='rp')
print("NEW", new_bc_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am relatively inexperienced with network algorithms in general, so take my answer and terminology here with a boulder of salt.

First off, I think your code actually does work.  Try, for example, redefining `org_net` as:

```
org_net = nx.random_geometric_graph(10, 3, seed=42)
```

This does indeed produce different betweenness centrality values for the edges.  From my reading of the definition of betweenness centrality, I think your problem is that the structure of the graph you've chosen actually means that the betweenness centrality values of your edges are essentially independent of weights.  So randomizing the weights results in the same values, regardless of how they're assigned.  Betweenness centrality only depends on the number of shortest paths, and if you draw your example network I think you'll see that randomizing the weights won't effect your  result:

```
org_net = gnp_random_connected_graph(10,.1)
pos = nx.spring_layout(org_net, seed=42)
nx.draw(org_net)
```

gives
[image: gnp graph plotted]

One other potentially conflicting problem that may have tripped up your troubleshooting is that networkx (as is often the case, unfortunately) silently ignores an issue that one might expect to throw an error.  For example, consider

```
bc_dict = nx.edge_betweenness_centrality(org_net,weight='banana')
```

This doesn't throw an error despite there being no edge attribute `'banana'`.

**EDIT:**
If you simply add a few edges to your 10-node `org_net`, you'll find that the betweenness centralities of your nodes do indeed change with the rest of your current code untouched:

```
a = [node for node in org_net.nodes()]

org_net.add_edge(a[4], a[9])
org_net.add_edge(a[6], a[9])
org_net.add_edge(a[7], a[9])

bc_dict = nx.edge_betweenness_centrality(org_net, weight='rp')
new_net = randomize_weights(org_net.copy())
new_bc_dict = nx.edge_betweenness_centrality(new_net, weight='rp')

bc_dict == new_bc_dict
```

returns `False`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately I cannot use the  nx.random_geometric_graph() or any other built in graph generator because I need the node and link objects for another part of the program. I've also tried increasing the node count to 100 and still see the issue. Which is why I thought that the objects could be causing an issue since the likelihood of the shortest paths changing due to weights should be quite high.  The last part is very helpful. I wish it would throw an error if the weight attribute cannot be found.

Comment: I understand you need to use your own graph generator, but I still think the structure of your graph means that the betweenness centrality of the nodes is independent of weights. The nodes through which each shortest path passes are essentially fixed.  I hypothesize there would have to be at least one cycle in the graph for betweenness centralities of the nodes to be affected by weights.  And yet, `nx.find_cycle(gnp_random_connected_graph(100,.1))` returns `'No cycle found'`.  Or am I misunderstanding the concept of betweenness centrality?

Comment: Also note my edit above where I add a few edges to your `org_net` and observe a change in the betweenness centralities of the nodes.